# SqlDataAdapter can it be used to access oracle db?

Tags: oracle, sqldataadapter

SqlDataAdapter can it be used to access oracle db?

Yes it says sql, but can it be used for oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - at least, not directly, you can of course execute SQL Server queries (SqlDataAdapter is SQL Server specific) that access data from Oracle, but you'll need a SQL Server involved.  Check out [Oracle and ADO.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7.aspx) on MSDN instead.

Comment: what do u mean by sql server involved? some thing like linked servers??

Comment: Indeed - exactly, although I'm not suggesting that you do this.  If you want to connect to an Oracle database directly then SqlDataAdapter and the other SqlClient classes are _not_ the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has deprecated its own Oracle drivers. Use [Oracle's drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html) instead. They will perform better than OleDB or ODBC drivers.

Answer (score 0):

[OleDbDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.aspx) or [OdbcDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdataadapter.aspx) classes?